# Why MySQL query execution plan changed after add new columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have a table and some data below:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.17, for macos10.12 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: testmysql
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.17-log


--
-- Table structure for table `t_strange_index`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `t_strange_index`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE `t_strange_index` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_time_status` (`create_time`,`status`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21
       DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `t_strange_index`
--

LOCK TABLES `t_strange_index` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `t_strange_index` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `t_strange_index` VALUES
        (1,1,1532745820825),(2,1,1532745864183),(3,1,1532745895207),
        (4,1,1532746773225),(5,1,1532746773225),(6,1,1532746773225),
        (7,1,1532746822078),(8,1,1532746822078),(9,1,1532746822078),
        (10,1,1532746979836),(11,1,1532746979836),(12,1,1532746979836),
        (13,9,1532763766641),(14,10,1532764510924),(15,10,1532765436500),
        (16,20,1532777350303),(17,9,1532777818806),(18,10,1532782628840),
        (19,10,1532782711973),(20,10,1532784164740);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `t_strange_index` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Then get the query execution plan for this SQL:

```
explain select * from t_strange_index
      where create_time >= 1532746822078
        and create_time <= 1532746979836
        and status = 1;
```

result:

```
 id | select_type | table           | partitions | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    
  1 | SIMPLE      | t_strange_index | NULL       | range | idx_time_status | idx_time_status | 9       | NULL |    6 |    10.00 | Using where; Using index
```

But after I add a new column,

```
alter table t_strange_index add column `new column` bigint(20) NOT NULL default 123;
```

the execution plan changes:

```
 id | select_type | table           | partitions | type | possible_keys   | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       
  1 | SIMPLE      | t_strange_index | NULL       | ALL  | idx_time_status | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   20 |     5.00 | Using where
```

it doesn't use the index anymore.

Could anyone tell me why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: see rows showing 20 in the new one. It seems you have inserted some rows after the first explain plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Covering Index**

You should notice your original EXPLAIN extra has Using Index. This is the indicator of covering index.

A covering index is an index that contains all the columns you need for the query.

When you add a new column, the idx_time_status is no longer a covering index (because you are selecting * and the new column is not in the index), and MySQL must go back to the original data. That's why MySQL decides that not using an index is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, you save my day.

Comment: @Lunatictwo Glad it's helpful. Could you accept it as the answer?

Comment: This is one argument against blindly using `SELECT *`.  Instead, spell out the columns you really need.

Comment: And "covering" is only one of several reasons for what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

"Covering index" is only part of the story.

This is backwards:

```
  KEY `idx_time_status` (`create_time`,`status`) USING BTREE
```

Start indexes with `=` test(s), then end with a range.  That is, this index will be better for your query:

```
  INDEX(status, create_time)
```

This won't have to step over rows with `status != 1`; the index filters them out.

But that does not explain the shunning of the index and switching to a table scan.  What explains that is that the range is probably more than about 20% of the table.  The Optimizer looks at statistics and debates whether it would be faster to use the index (when only a few rows are needed) or ignore the index and simply scan the table (when many rows are needed).

If your test case had more row in the given range, it might have a different `EXPLAIN`.

See my [*index builder cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: yes, you are right, the original index should be changed to (status, create_time)